# Mac connects to anonymous wireless networks randomly

Tags: wifi, router

I have my own router and it has a strong signal full bars, but sometimes when I leave my macbook for a time and come back I notice that it connects other random anonymous wireless networks.

how can I disable it, so it only connects to my router?

Comment: Did you enable the Ask to Join Networks in sys pref networks, and deleted all network profiles that you do not want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to `System Preferences` > `Network` > `Wifi`
- Click on Advanced
- Remove the preferred networks from the list by using `-` button

[image]